# Pandas DataFrame plot changing values when using date as x

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Im having problems with ploting Pandas DataFrame data:

My df looks like this:

```
data        var   es
2014-02-02  0.5   0.54
2014-02-03  0.43  0.5
2014-02-04  0.23  0.3
```

Plotting it like this:

```py
var[250:].plot(y=['var', 'es'], kind='line', figsize=(20,5))
```

gives the following result:
[image: plot1]

But using 'data' column as x in plot makes the data change values on the plot:

```py
var[250:].plot(x='data', y=['var', 'es'], kind='line', figsize=(20,5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using pandas.to_datetime() function to convert dates from string to Datetime without specifying the format. That caused the data mixed up